# How can I sort categories using json?

Tags: android, json

I have an android app which fetches data from json file and displays it in the app, but when rendered it appears randomly and unordered as in json file

This is the simple code used in json:-

```
"Categories": [
    {
      "name": "text1"
    },
    {
      "name": "text2"
    },
    {
      "name": "text3"
    }
```

What I want is to arrange these `categories` to appear in the application in the same order as the one you formatted in the json file

Can anyone help me here? Thanks!